# Are connections in general relativity spin-3 objects?

Tags: general-relativity, representation-theory

If we see metric-compatible connections (not Levi-Civita) then can we say that the connections are spin-3 objects? If not, when do we say that an object with $J$ index is a spin-$J$ object ($J \in \mathbb{Z}$) ?

Comment: This link should help you https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Spin_connection. In the tretradic formulation of general relativity, we are using spin(1,3) connection.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux What do you mean by spin(1, 3)? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: spin(1,3) is the algebra of Spin(1,3)=SL(2,C) which is the double cover of the Lorentz group. This notation for SL(2,C) enlightens the global hyperbolic structure of space-time. spin(1,3) is spanned by the Dirac gamma matrices commutators. So there will be two indices for spin(1,3)-valued gauge connections, which is the case for spin connection.

Comment: If we are speaking about spin connection $e_{\mu}^{a}$ it has two indices, as mentioned above, and under each of it transform like a vector - a vector in global space, to which the greek index $\mu$ corresponds, and $a$ - vector index in a local space, so in that sense it has spin 1 with respect to both of these transfromation. However, if you mean $\nabla_\mu$ - it is just an ordinary Lorentz vector - spin 1.

Comment: @spiridon_the_sun_rotator $e^a_\mu$ are the coefficients of tetrads, not the spin connection. The spin connection components are written $\omega^{a b}_\mu$. a and b are the two indices I mentioned.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux So, essentially the spin connection is a spin-1 object. Just like a gluon field. Right? Then how come graviton is spin-2?

Comment: Unfortunalely I am not qualified for the graviton case. For me it is juste a quantum exciation of the metric tensor, whose coefficients are $g_{\mu \nu}=\eta_{I J} e^I_\mu e^J_\nu$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Spin and rank**

*(For simplicity I will discuss only integer spin fields)*

It is not precise to identify the rank of the field to the spin of the field.
For instance, a spin $s=0$ field is usually best described by a scalar field.
$$\phi(x)$$ But we can form tensors of higher rank by taking derivatives of the original field
$$B_\mu = \partial_\mu \phi(x)$$
Here I already know that the physical content of my vector field $B_\mu$ is a spin $s=0$ field.

In general, one needs more equations to specify the spin of the field. Weinberg's Qauntum Theory of Fields ch5. does a wonderful job at explaining the bottom up approach - if we want to describe a field of some spin $s$, let's see into which objects we can pack it up, and see what conditions these objects must satisfy.

Once the candidates are tried out, one can infer that, if you want massive relativistic fields of definite integer spin they must satisfy the following equations (the dots indicate that any rank tensor is possible):
\begin{align}
(\Box + m^2)\phi^{\mu\nu...} = 0\\
\eta_{\mu\nu}\phi^{\mu\nu....}=0\\
\partial_\mu\phi^{\mu...}=0\\
\phi^{\mu\nu...} - \text{ Totally symmetric in all indices}
\end{align}
(On-shell, completely symmetric, traceless and transverse)

Then, if the previous relations are valid, the rank of the tensor corresponds to the spin.
For massive fields of any integer spin, this was figured out by Fierz and Pauli, for massless field of any spin by Fronsdal. The massless case is more subtle, it turns out that if we want Lorentz covariance, we neeed our fields to also be gauge invariant.

**Spin 2**

The reason we say general relativity is described by a spin two field is because when we linearise the theory around flat space, the perturbation field $h_{\mu\nu}$ is a spin two field

$$g_{\mu\nu} = \eta_{\mu\nu} + h_{\mu\nu}$$

Now, in this linearised view, the connection would be

$$\Gamma_{\mu \nu}^{\sigma}=\frac{1}{2} \eta^{\sigma \rho}\left(\partial_{\nu} h_{\rho \mu}+\partial_{\mu} h_{\rho \nu}-\partial_{\rho} h_{\mu \nu}\right)$$

and it still describes a spin $s=2$ field, for the same reason above vector field describes a scalar field.

Comment: What about connections that are not Levi-Civita? Then are the connections spin-3 objects ?

Comment: In the linearised sense, the object should be able to satisfy the equations above (be totally symmetric, traceless and transverse, after some possible gauge fixing). For instance, the Weitzeböck connection in teleparallel gravity can be linearised and still you can see its content is the derivative of the original field, it does not satisfy the conditions above.
I don't know whether there are obstructions to using an object, whose components are a totally symmetric three index tensor, as an affine connection, but I do not know of an example.